# Jquery equation for each table row

Tags: jquery, row, each

I'm having a bit of trouble with the code below and I'm too new to jQuery to figure it out.

```
function calcExpiration(){
    var getState = jQuery( "#state" ).text();
    var getcalldate = jQuery( "#date" ).text();
    var date = new Date( getcalldate );
    if (getState == "KY" || getState == "IN"){
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 30);
    }
    if (getState == "WV" || getState == "OH"){
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 10);
    }
    var expmonth = date.getMonth()+1;
    var expdate = date.getDate();
    var expyear = date.getFullYear();
    jQuery( "#expiration" ).html( expmonth + "/" + expdate + "/" + expyear);
}
calcExpiration();
```

I have multiple rows of information within a table and I'd like to have the expiration calculate for each row and the above code is only working for the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert of jQuery, but have you tried this to do what I think you are trying to achieve?

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Expiration</th>
</tr>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>KY</td>
        <td>02-12-2015</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>IN</td>
        <td>01-20-2014</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>WV</td>
        <td>03-02-2014</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>OH</td>
        <td>04-05-2012</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

jQuery

```
$('table tbody tr:not(":first")').each(function (e) {
var state = $('td:eq(0)', this).text();
var getcalldate = $('td:eq(1)', this);
var dsplit = getcalldate.text().split("-");
var d=new Date(dsplit[2],dsplit[0],dsplit[1]-1);
var expDates = $('td:eq(2)', this);

var expmonth = d.getMonth() + 1;
var expdate = d.getDate();
var expyear = d.getFullYear();
var resultDate = expmonth + "-" + expdate + "-" + expyear

if (state == "KY" || state == "IN") {
    expDates.text(resultDate);
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 30);
} else if (state == "WV" || state == "OH") {
    expDates.html(resultDate);
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 10);
}

});
```

Comment: You didn't select jQuery as the Framework in your fiddle, that's why it doesn't work. On the left side of the screen "Frameworks & Extensions" select jQuery. This is my fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emfuentes27/84oemvvb/)

Comment: Clearly another noob mistake. haha I've got a version of your code that I used on my example and it works pretty nice. Thanks!!

One thing that isn't clear to me is when dealing with a month that isn't 31 days long it subtracts that from the actual number of days for that month.

If the month isn't 31 days long (e.g., February is 28 days) then it subtracts 3 off of my "+30" calculation in the if statement for KY/IN.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you're using ids improperly. In an HTML document there's only meant to be a single element with one id, so `jQuery('#expiration')` may return only the first matching element even if multiple elements have that same ID.

I'd suggest you change `expiration` from an id to a class. In general, you can't go wrong using classes instead of ids as Jquery handles.

Also, I'd think of a more descriptive name. `.expiration` is general and makes the above Jquery code hard to read out of context; perhaps something like `.expiration_date_updatable` would be more evocative? Maybe that's a bad example but in general, use *very* precise and descriptive class names whenever those classes are hooking into Jquery behavior. Do it for the readers of your code (including your future self).

Comment: I switched out the ID for the class and now I get NaN/NaN/NaN.

The table dynamically adds rows based on an input form. Classes and ID's will always be the same unless I iterate an array which I'd prefer not to do so that I can apply CSS more efficiently elsewhere.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference if content is dynamically getting added to the table; at any point, when `calcExpiration()` is run, the bottom line like `jQuery('.expiration').html(...)` will select all matching elements present in the DOM (ie. on the page) at that moment. What it *does* with those elements is another matter. If you get NaN showing up in the page HTML, that means you have something wrong with your calculation logic (use `console.log("blah blah")` statements to troubleshoot these) but that's an entirely separate problem.

Answer (score 0):

ID(#) will always work for first element with given id, to make this work for all you should work with class(.)... Below is an simple example

```
<p class="test-tag">Demo</p>
<p class="test-tag">Demo</p>
<p class="test-tag">Demo</p>
<p class="test-tag">Demo</p>
<p class="test-tag">Demo</p>
<a class="test">Btn1</a>
<a class="test">Btn2</a>
<a class="test">Btn3</a>
<a class="test">Btn4</a>

jQuery( '.test' ).click(function() {
    var time = jQuery.now();
    jQuery('.test-tag').empty().html(time);
});
```